# Speaking urls in Ext:news with multiple plugins

Tags: symfony, routes, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions, tx-news

I have a problem with the site configuration of news when there are two news plugins on one page (TYPO3 v9.5.20). There is a list view and a tag list as navigation for the tags ([screenshot1][1]). In the list view I am able to click on tags and only news with these tags are displayed. This works and the URLs fit. So everything is ok.
But if I activate the tag list plugin I get an error ([screenshot2][2]): `The controller "News" is not allowed by plugin "Pi1". Please check for TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin() in your ext_localconf.php.`

The site configuration in config.yaml looks like this:

```
routeEnhancers:
  News:
    type: Extbase
    limitToPages:
      - 141
      - 142
    extension: News
    plugin: Pi1
    routes:
      - routePath: 'page/{page}'
        _controller: 'News::list'
        _arguments:
          page: '@widget_0/currentPage'
      - routePath: '/{news-title}'
        _controller: 'News::detail'
        _arguments:
          news-title: news
      - routePath: '/{category-name}'
        _controller: 'News::list'
        _arguments:
          category-name: overwriteDemand/categories
      - routePath: '/{tag-name}'
        _controller: 'News::list'
        _arguments:
          tag-name: overwriteDemand/tags
    defaultController: 'News::list'
    defaults:
      page: '0'
    aspects:
      news-title:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: tx_news_domain_model_news
        routeFieldName: path_segment
      page:
        type: StaticRangeMapper
        start: '1'
        end: '100'
      category-name:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: sys_category
        routeFieldName: slug
      tag-name:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: tx_news_domain_model_tag
        routeFieldName: slug


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsFux.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2IZn.png
```